# Binary conditional coding in Dplyr

Tags: dplyr, dataset, rstudio

I am trying to do binary conditional coding in R:

Lets say we want to create a new columns in mtcars dataset called `binary_col` that would be equal to 1 if qsec columns is higher or equal to 16 and 0 else.

Using code below is not working:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- mtcars
df %>% head


df %>% mutate(binary_col = if (qsec >= 16) {
  binary_col = 1
})

df %>% head
```

Answer (score 3):

try

df %>%
mutate(binary_col = ifelse(qsec >= 16, 1,0))

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `if_else` for this. The following works completely fine:

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(binary_col = qsec >= 16)
```

If you want 0's and 1's, you just need to use `as.integer()` on the binary vector.